# DataGrid вернуться после обновления на ту же запись

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, mvvm-light

Есть DataGrid, допустим я изменил какие то данные в строки, вызвал обновление(Select к БД). И хочу чтобы после обновление осталась выделена та, запись которую редактировал, и проскролил если запись далеко внизу.

Comment: А в чем проблема? Запомните строку, потом восстановите и перемотайте на нее с помощью `ScrollIntoView`

Comment: @АндрейNOP проблема в том, что я стиль MaterialDesign сбил своим и не заметил, что выделение серое и на белом не видно)

Answer (score 0):

сначала получаем текущую запись:

```
int cr =dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Index;
```

а после загрузки можно перейти к ячейки следующим образом:

```
dataGridView1.CurrentCell = dataGridView1.Rows[cr].Cells.OfType<DataGridViewCell>().First(c => c.Visible);
```

Обратите внимание Cells.OfType().First(c => c.Visible) - дает первую видимую ячейку в вашей строке.
По идее это должно помочь, проверьте синтаксис, так как писал по памяти.